# Tunnelling data through HTTP using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, tunnel, chunked

I am trying to implement a small server-side solution for remotely connecting to my home network. Basically like using a custom-proxy, since my ISP does not allow incoming connections (Dish/Hughes Net).

I've setup a c#/wpf/desktop application to connect to my server/website via TCP. Once the connection is established, some HTTP headers are pushed through:

```
"GET http://.../api.ashx?connect HTTP/1.1"
"Host: ...:80"
"Connection: keep-alive"
"Content-Encoding: UTF-8"
"Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
""
{data}
0\r\n
```

This solution is only working once the request has completed. The problem is that the incoming data is being buffered before it is processed by the GenericHandler, and being sent "all-at-once". I need to find a way for data being sent to ASP.net to remain streamed/chunked, so it can be processed asynchronously.

Comment: How are you connecting to this if your ISP doesn't allow incoming connections? Is your web server hosted somewhere else (i.e. by a different ISP)? If you have a web server hosted by a different ISP, what are you trying to solve? Can you define "connecting to my home network"? I go straight to thinking some kind of RDP session. And if that's the case, why are you using HTTP as the transport?

Comment: @itsme86: Dish does not allow incoming connections (primarily port-forwarding). So from my network I can access the internet, and receive network responses.
However I can not connect to any devices on my network remotely (from an outside network). The modem provided by hughes-net blocks any incoming connections (that are not responses), and/or anything not on port 80.

So my solution is to have a spare pc on my network connect to my [remote] server. Then my work/travelling pc will connect to the same server, and data will be tunnelled through HTTP using TCP/IP

Comment: And where is this running in relation to your home network? There were several questions in my previous comment.

Comment: post updated. Home Network & Work Network are connecting to same remote server, and server is simply tunnelling data between two active TCP connections. The problem is that ASP net is buffering incoming data before I can process it. Since I am sending streaming-data, this is a critical problem.

Comment: Would a simple TCP relay work for you? There's a million free ones out there. If you just want to relay TCP traffic, I would avoid doing it with HTTP if possible.

Comment: It will not. This is part of a much larger project that will have multiple users, and it is important I come up with my own dynamic tunnelling solution.

Also, I am able to catch the TCP connection event using IHttpModule & BeginRequest. But I can not figure out how to disable ASP from buffering the whole stream before sending it to the IHttpHandler.